# What proof of parent/child relationship is required at southern border ports of entry?

Tags: united-states, immigration

This question is specific to those seeking asylum.
At the White house press conference today I understood the DHS secretary to say that (paraphrasing) when a woman and child present themselves at the entry points we **MAY** assume that the child is an unaccompanied minor and the woman is a smuggler. The woman is now arrested and will await trial, and the child is placed in care of HHS. We do this (separation of child) for the protection of the child.

Presumably, if the parent can prove (at the border control point) that they are not smuggling, but rather seeking asylum for themselves and **their child**, they would be handled differently.

It seems that the key is proving a parent/child relationship (thus avoiding the smuggling accusation).

So, exactly what proof is expected to establish that parent/child relationship ?

While a birth certificate is the obvious answer, how can border agents associate a proffered birth certificate (assuming it's available) with the actual child, particularly if the child (because of age) can't be interrogated ?

Comment: Why is this question not a solicitation of opinion?  Clearly law enforcement would not publicize the methods it uses to determine if someone is trying to deceive them.  So the only way to answer this question is to speculate.

Comment: @grovkin: No opinion here, Customs and Border Patrol do publish a variety documents can be used to enter. I'm not asking about methods of deception, or how to detect deception. Rather, I'm asking  very practical question, how can an agent be certain that (for example) a woman with a two year old child is actually that child's mother. What documentation or evidence would a woman seeking asylum need have to satisfy an agent's doubt (about parent/child relationship)?

Comment: What you say implies that absolute certainty is possible.  Even if all the required documents are presented, an agent may experience doubt and, in those cases, should exercise their judgement (informed by their internalized training) to decide how and whether to look into it further.  There is a reason why there are people rather than scanning machines at the border.  They are expected to make decisions from time to time.  Regimenting the decisions too much would make their response less secure because it would only serve to reduce their judgement.

Comment: So you are either expressing an opinion that they should act according to published procedures and nothing else, which would be a rant on your part.  Or you are asking whether it can be determined how they are trained to react in situations which are not published.  And that's soliciting an opinion.

Comment: I find it amazing how commentors work so hard to attack a simple question. Let's begin this way: Your friend in Honduras is going to try to seek asylum in the US. She asks you: "What documentation or evidence do I need to bring with me to prove my child is really my child?

Comment: If you are interested in the bureaucratic technicalities of traveling to the United States than the political backgrounds, then this is more of a question for https://travel.stackexchange.com. I will migrate it there.

Comment: I am asking specifically about the current handling of amnesty seekers and the policy promulgated by the current administration, that is clearly within the scope of "governments, policies, and processes".. BTW, the folks at travel have already voted that this question does not belong in their section. Please do not migrate.

Comment: On review of my last comment I intended to say **asylum seekers**

Comment: I think this question can be answered if it is modified as "What guidance does the US Government offer asylum seekers to prove that they are the legal guardians of accompying children?"  However, I don't know whether that question belongs here or on law.se